# Must bin/roslyn be published every time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm publishing over webDav to webserver; the site is both classic asp and new c# aspx.

Currently it is only two pages, but the majority of the time is spent uploading bin/roslyn.

The time of the files in bin/roslyn changes to the time of publish.

Is this upload nessecary every time; does the files really change?
I'm not asking if bin/roslyn can be removed.

Is there a way to just upload the changed files?
I'm uploading over 4G network, while it is not exactly slow, it's not wirespeed either.

I don't uplode the entire website; there are a lot of old .asp and images I haven't pulled to my workstation, so I don't delete the existing files first.

```
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder bin...
Publishing folder bin/roslyn...
Publishing folder xml...
Web App was published successfully file:///Y:/
```

I'm not sure how to get a list of all files, but I'll write a few names:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
```

This is in descending size; already this is about 10MB.

Comment: Could you update your post with the complete list of file names being uploaded?

Comment: Complete list is a little hard, unless you can point me to a logfile. I have added the directories and the first four largest files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used webDav before, but it seems like work the same as ftp publish.

If you want to publish only part which have changed, there is two way:

1. use web deploy
2. publish to local file then chose only upload the part has changed

### use web deploy

there is article of how to set up web deploy at microsoft docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later

essentially install web deploy at iis, then when publishing in VS, chose web deploy

### deploy to local folder then upload change part

in VS, publish to local folder, then manually upload file which have changed (if you use version control, who wouldn't, you should be able to tell which files has changed)

Comment: Version control won't help much, as version control controls the aspx.cs, while the resulting dll's are what's being uploaded to the server.

Comment: @LeifNeland it does help, you version control cs file, so if your cs files are the same, then you can assume dll is the same, hence not need to upload dll.  However, if you have modified cs files since last upload, then that means dll has change - so only upload relevant dll up.  There is more work to do if you manage manually, hence web deploy is better option - which essentially do the same thing as describe above

Comment: As you said, web deploy only uploads the changed parts. tnx.